# Quality difference of same bitmap

Tags: android

I am using the **same bitmap** captured by camera for *pixel by pixel comparison*. But the quality is low when the bitmap is transferred from the below code.(direct from camera capture)

```
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    var_Bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    var_imageview_browse.setImageBitmap(var_Bitmap);
    var_imageview_browse.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    var_Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(var_Bitmap, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, false);
```

But, the quality of the **same bitmap** is fine, when i get it from the camera gallery using the below code

```
      imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            var_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
          

        var_imageview_browse.setImageBitmap(var_Bitmap);
        var_imageview_browse.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        var_Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(var_Bitmap, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, false);
```

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: The first piece of code gives you only a thumbnail of the image. No wonder. You should change your camera intent to obtain the full image.

Comment: ok. I got it. Can you suggest any simple android library which manages camera api  for all android versions?

Comment: No need for a library. You use already a simple intent. But it gives you only a thumbnail. Add an extra with an uri for a file from a file provider. Thats all. Pretty standard.